# Uniformly independent distributed random variables. Compute the sum.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X,Y$ be two i.i.d random variables on $[-1,1]$. I want to obtain $Z=X+Y$ via convolution as follows:

$f_Z(z)=\int^\infty_{-\infty} f_X(x)f_Y(x-z)\mathrm{d}x$.

I know that there are many related threads, and I have read and understood them, but they are only on the intervall $[0,1]$ and the intervall $[-1,1]$ somehow makes problems to me.

Here is what I got so far:

I know that $f_X$ is equal to one only at $-1\le x \le 1$ and our integral reduced to $f_Z(z)=\int^\infty_{-\infty}f_Y(x-z)\mathrm{d}x$. Also it is obvious that $-1\le x-z \le 1$ or equivalently $x-1\le z \le x+1$ must hold. I now divided $z$ into two intervalls

1. $-2\le z \le 0$: Now I took that $-1\le x\le z+1$ and computed
   $\int^{z+1}_{-1}\mathrm{d}x=z+2, \text{for} -2\le z \le 0$
2. $0\le z \le 2$: Same procedure, but with $1\ge x\ge z-1$. I get
   $\int^1_{z-1}\mathrm{d}x=2-z \ \text{for}\  0\le z\le 2$

The problem is, that this is not a pdf, as it is not normed to unity.

Comment: $f_X(x)=1/2$ for $-1\leq x\leq 1. $ Same stands for $f_Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made few mistakes.

First of all $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2}$, $x\in [-1, 1]$ and $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2}$, $y\in [-1,1]$. All of other computations are right, just missing $\frac{1}{4}$ term.

So you get:

$$f_Z(z)=\frac{z+2}{4}, z\in [-2,0], \quad  f_Z(z)=\frac{2-z}{4}, z\in [0,2]$$

And it's easy to see:
$$\int_{-2}^2f_Z(z)dz=\int_{-2}^0\frac{z+2}{4}dz+\int_0^2\frac{2-z}{4}dz=1. $$